# R markdown with RGL gives "You must enable Javascript to view this page properly" error

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, htmlwidgets

I have a downloadHandler() in Shiny that generates an html document using R markdown. This document generates rgl plots, which are added to the document using hook_webgl. The application is running on a Shiny server. Everything works fine the first time the download button is used, but on the following occasions I get the error "You must enable Javascript to view this page properly". I am using rglwidgets, but I get the same issues using shinyRGL.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.13.2       rmarkdown_0.9.5    knitr_1.12.3       rglwidget_0.1.1434
[5] rgl_0.95.1441

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] htmlwidgets_0.6 magrittr_1.5    R6_2.1.2        tools_3.2.4
 [5] htmltools_0.3.5 Rcpp_0.12.4     jsonlite_0.9.19 digest_0.6.9
 [9] xtable_1.8-2    httpuv_1.3.3    mime_0.4
```

Comment: Check the browser javascript console log, and also Shiny Server log

Comment: The issues happen already when the document is created, so it shouldn't be browser related. I've also used the same code on my desktop pc with the same results.

Comment: I didnt mean that its related to your browser or the server, just that these are the places where Shiny keeps more detailed log about the app and you might find useful information